# Regex is matching quotes when I do not want it to

Tags: regex

Here is a link to the demo http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDwsSBlJlY2lwZRjrstAmDA/index.html

Select the Java one and look at the input. You can supply arguments either within quotation marks or without. However, when the regex captures the groups, I don't want it to capture the quotes for the arguments that are enclosed within quotes. It's confusing because the quotes are out of the brackets so I don't know why they're being captured.

How can I fix this?

EDIT:

To clarify, I want the output to look like this:

```
hello-world
hi
 this is \"
\\
sparta
```

Comment: please post your example and expected output here

Comment: Java do not supports `branch reset (?|)` (_if supported, this would have been too easy_)..we can use lookbehind and lookahead but there will be some extra data that will be picked

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want double quotes to be caught then you need to avoid matching them using zero-width assertions - lookarounds:

```
(?<=")(?!\s+")(?:[^\\"]+|\\")+(?=")|[^"\s]+
```

[Live demo](http://fiddle.re/5ytj3a)